# How should I implement my mongoose userSchema with authentication?

Tags: node.js, authentication, mongoose, passport.js, jwt

I'm new trying to create a **RESTful API** with Node.js, Express, utilizing **mongoose** with mongodb, so I'm sorry if this question might sound silly.

The API should allow **students** to **organize** their **information**. A student would be able to **authenticate** and from there on he could **add Semesters, and for each Semester he could add Courses, for each Course he could add annotations and so on...**

**eg.** Student A: [1st Semester: [Course A: [Annotation 1], [Annotation 2]...], [Course B: [Annotation 1], [Annotation 2]...]]

When **student A** send a request to **GET ALL Semesters**, he should only get **his** information.

I would be utilizing JWT with Passport.js. So far I have this, however I need to add the collections: Semesters -> Courses -> Annotations.

**Should I put all of them inside the userSchema or should I create separate subdocuments for each one of them?** What's the best way for it to be done?

Thank you very much!

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ //Cria schema do usuario
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    hash: String //Senha criptografada com o salt
    salt: String //Utilizado para 'salgar' a senha
});

userSchema.methods.setPassword(password){
    this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
    this.hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');
};

userSchema.methods.validatePassword(password){
    var hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');
    return hash == this.hash;
};

userSchema.methods.generateJwt(){
    var expiry = new Date();
    expiry.setDate(expiry.getDate() + 7);

    return jwt.sign({
        _id: this.id,
        email: this.email,
        name: this.name,
        exp: parseInt(expiry.getTime() / 1000),
    }, "MY_SECRET");
};
```

Comment: All the examples of authentication I see create a userSchema with name and password. What about the user information? Where should I put it? How am I going to only retrieve that user's information?